# Show text leaving some space from text view boarder

Tags: android, android-layout, textview

I have to show questions in a text view.

I used wrap_content for it.

I colored the boarder of the text view.

My problem is the text shown touches the colored boundary line,but i want some space between text and boundary.

suggest some idea.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Add padding to your **TextView**

like this

```
android:paddingLeft="5dp";
android:paddingRight="5dp";
```